# how to apply a function on MultiIndex groups

Tags: pandas

I have a MultiIndex pandas serie

```
df=
code       names                                
B1         Aaaaa                                        7
           Abaaa                                        7
           Bbbbb                                        2
           Bcccc                                        6 

B2         Ssss                                         1
           Yyyy                                         1
           Bbbb                                         1
           BBbb                                         1
```

I'm looking to return the index with the maximum value. if there is more than one index sharing the maximum value, we must choose the first alphabetical index.

```
df=
code       names                                
B1         Aaaaa                                        7

B2         BBbb                                         1
```

I've tried to use this code

```
df=df.reset_index().groupby('names',as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.max())
```

but it returned the wrong pandas serie.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.loc[df.groupby(level=0).idxmax()]
```

or

```
df.groupby(level=0).tail(1)
```

---

```
d = [['B1','Aaaaa',7],['B1','Abaaa', 7],['B1','Bbbbb',2],['B1','Bcccc',6],\
     ['B2','Ssss',1],['B2','Yyyy',1],['B2','Bbbb',1],['B2','BBbb',1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns = ['code','names','x'])
df.set_index(['code','names'],inplace=True)
```

---

**df:**

```
        x
code    names   
B1      Aaaaa   7
        Abaaa   7
        Bbbbb   2
        Bcccc   6
B2      Ssss    1
        Yyyy    1
        Bbbb    1
        BBbb    1
```

---

```
df.loc[df.sort_values(['code','names'], ascending=[True,False]).groupby('code')['x'].idxmax()]
```

**Result:**

```
                x
code    names   
B1      Abaaa   7
B2      Yyyy    1
```

**EDIT:**

Set ascending = [True,True]

```
df.loc[df.sort_values(['code','names'], ascending=[True,True]).groupby('code')['x'].idxmax()]
```

---

```
                x
code    names   
B1      Aaaaa   7
B2      BBbb    1
```

Comment: your code should return the first alphabetical name for rows that share the same maximum value.@Pygirl

Comment: Do ascending=[True,True]